# Azure web app with PDFtk (PHP laravel backend)

Tags: php, laravel, azure, pdftk, voyager

I am trying to override the Voyager admin panel read view with a PDF form that is filled from fields in the DB.

I achieved this through FPDM with PDFtk on localhost on a windows machine. The problem is that the web app is hosted on Azure. Is there any way to install PDFtk on the Azure side.

And if not, is there another solution to approach this situation?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your real question is how to install PDFtk on Azure WebApp for Windows.

Yes, I tried to install it and run a command `pdftk.exe *.pdf cat output combined.pdf` successfully.

Here is my steps below.

1. I downloaded an installation `PDFtk Free` from PDFtk offical website https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/.

   [image]
2. I installed it into `D:\Program Files\PDFtk` my local Windows machine and move into the directory `PDFtk\bin`.

   [image]
3. I was ready for two PDF files, such as `Google.pdf` and `Bing.pdf` which I got them via browse and print them as pdf in Chrome.

   [image]
4. I opened the Kudu console of my Azure WebApp, and command `cd site\wwwroot` to move to `wwwroot` path , and then I drag and drop these four files above in Step 2 & 3 into it.

   [image]
5. Finally, I tried to only run `pdftk.exe` to get the help information successfully, and then to run `pdftk.exe *.pdf cat output combined.pdf` command and it works fine to get the `combined.pdf` file as Step 4 shown.

   [image]

So if you want to invoke it in programming, you just invoke its absolute path `D:\home\site\wwwroot\pdftk.exe` with its parameters from your code, it will work fine for you.

Note: Due to the [`Win32k.sys (User32/GDI32) Restrictions`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions) of [`Azure Web App sandbox`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox), not every pdf conversion software can be installed on Azure WebApp as my did above. So `PDFtk` is a special software which not be implemented by using GDI.